# Not able to use record_android_trace command for Perfetto from command line

Tags: android, performance, profiling, systrace, perfetto

I've been following [Quickstart: Record traces on Android](https://perfetto.dev/docs/quickstart/android-tracing#recording-a-trace) and also watching the demonstration and guide - [Android app performance with Perfetto](https://youtu.be/YEX26m89fco?t=2077),  after running the command record_android_trace I'm getting this error -

[image: Error while record_android_trace wit the config]

***Has anyone got this error?***

Comment: Can you please provide some more information like OS version, a snippet of the config etc? Without knowing a bit more information, it's difficult to provide any guidance.

Comment: What happens when you execute `adb devices`?